# SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I'm using Laravel with postgres and i'm having this error:

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function paymentrun(integer, date, double precision, text) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT paymentRun( ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: SELECT paymentRun( :buyer_id::integer, :payment_date::DATE, :paid_amount::double precision, :paydetails::text);)

Where I have this function: 
EDIT::the function is way bigger, but i think it's not needed to show

```
CREATE FUNCTION "paymentRun"(buyer_id integer, payment_date DATE, paid_amount double precision, payDetails text) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
row_STab "SearchTable"%rowtype;
curProd  "KeysForSale"%rowtype;
totalPrice double precision;
returnedPID integer;
BEGIN
```

And I'm calling the fuction in this way:

```
DB::select("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;");
DB::select('BEGIN TRANSACTION;');

$sendToSQL = '';

for($i = 0; $i<session('cart_number'); $i++)
    $sendToSQL .= '(' . $cart_array[$i] . '),';
$sendToSQL = rtrim($sendToSQL,",");
$sendToSQL .= ';';

DB::select('INSERT INTO "SearchTable"(product_id) VALUES' . $sendToSQL);

//DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT paymentRun'))->where(Auth::id(), date('Y/m/d'),'PayPal', 10000, 'qualquer');
DB::select('SELECT paymentRun(
    :buyer_id::integer,
    :payment_date::DATE,
    :paid_amount::double precision,
    :paydetails::text);', 

    ['buyer_id' => Auth::id(), 
     'payment_date' => date('Y/m/d'),
     'paid_amount' => 10000, 
     'paydetails' =>'qualquer'
 ]);
//DB::select('DELETE FROM "SearchTable";');
DB::select('COMMIT;');
```

What i'm doing wrong?
I tried several aways, but no a single one has come to a decent result.

Thanks

Comment: Using function CAST() i get the same error. Using DB::raw() it skips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the function with the name within double quotes and different cases.

```
CREATE FUNCTION "paymentRun" ...
```

If you do so casing matters when the object is subsequently addressed. So you need to change

```
DB::select('SELECT paymentRun(
```

to

```
DB::select('SELECT "paymentRun"(
```

in order to address the function correctly.